# Is there a Rails way to get all associated objects of an ActiveRecord::Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, orm

Let's suppose we've 2 models:

```rb
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

and we want to get a list of all Books - on a page where we're already querying all Authors along with their associated books as follow:

```rb
@authors = Author.all.includes(:books)
```

We could do it using Ruby as so:

```
@authors.map(&:books) # returns an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
```

But is there a Rails' way of doing it that would return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` ?

Comment: I am sorry but your question is unclear to me. Why don't you use `Book.all` when you want to load all books? Or do you want to present the books grouped by their author?

Comment: Wouldn't this result in an additional query ? What troubles me is that, if I do `Book.all`, I feel like I'm querying the same objects twice: with `Author.all.includes(:books)` and `Book.all`

Comment: `Author.all.includes(:books)` does internally very likely two queries (but not n) anyway. And `Author.all.includes(:books)` has the additional overhead of matching all the associations after loading. That means if you need all record of both lists, but not grouped then `Author.all` and `Book.all` is certainly faster, then `Author.all.includes(:books)` plus mapping.

Answer (score 2):

> `extract_associated(association)`
>
> Extracts a named association from the relation. The named association is first preloaded, then the individual association records are collected from the relation. Like so:
>
> ```
> account.memberships.extract_associated(:user)
> # => Returns collection of User records
> ```
>
> This is short-hand for:
>
> ```
>   account.memberships.preload(:user).collect(&:user)
> ```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-extract_associated

Comment: `collect` is an alias of `map` so its pretty much identitical to your initial method.

Comment: Good to know, though it also returns a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`